# JavaScript: modify prototype of an object's variable?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype-programming

Here is an object:

```
var obj = new function(){
    this.prop = {};
}
```

and I try to do something like:
`obj.prop.prototype["new_attr"] = "some_value";`

What I'd like to do, is permanently modify `obj.prop` to contain the new attributes. From what I understood, all "Objects" had the prototype, but JavaScript is telling me `prop` doesn't have prototype.

Maybe I'm taking the wrong approach (in trying to permanently modify `prop`), but I'd at least like to know why the code above doesn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically you access the `prototype` object from the constructor function, but you can get it from an object as well, but not using `.prototype`.

The unofficial way (not supported in all browsers) to get the prototype object of an object is with the `__proto__` property. (I believe it is deprecated in the browsers that support(ed) it).

The official ECMAScript 5 way (also not supported in all browsers) to get the prototype object of an object is to use `Object.getPrototypeOf()`.

In your case `.prop` is referencing an object literal, so you already know that the prototype is `Object.prototype`.

```
Object.getPrototypeOf( {} ) === Object.prototype;  // true
```

Note that it is almost always a bad idea to extend `Object.prototype`.

---

> *"Maybe I'm taking the wrong approach (in trying to permanently modify prop), but I'd at least like to know why the code above doesn't work."*

If you're just trying to modify the object referenced by `.prop`, then simply do:

```
obj.prop.new_attr = "some_value";
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish what you are trying to do but you need to add the prop object to the constructors prototype:

```
var Obj = function() {};

Obj.prototype.prop = { bar: 'bar value' };

var obj_1 = new Obj();

console.log(obj_1.prop.bar); //bar value

obj_1.prop.foo = 'foo value';

var obj_2 = new Obj();

console.log(obj_2.prop.foo); //foo value
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the prop attribute is empty. Before you'll be able to modify object.prop, you need to initialize prop first to a default value.

See the following references: [Extending JavaScript Objects and Classes](http://phrogz.net/js/classes/ExtendingJavaScriptObjectsAndClasses.html)
[Introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)
[A re-introduction to JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/a_re-introduction_to_javascript)

HTH. Cheers.